# Get only one record from android database

Tags: android, database

I need to get only 1 record from android database... Spent hours in google but can't to write query as need. I know its a shame.  Someone please help me. My query is below...

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
```

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: We need a little more info.  Do you have anything else?  A name, A phone number, something,  You could simply read one record from the cursor.

Comment: Generraly want to get only 1 record from URI "ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI" and check if record will have row "ACCOUNT_TYPE". If will, then query all emails with sort ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.google' ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, " LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Does this only take one element from a query result, that contains potentially more elements? Or does it actually invoke a query, that has a result size of 1?

Comment: @SME_Dev it will return a cursor which has exactly only one row (or 0 rows if nothing could be retervied)

Comment: This doesn't clarify my question yet. The Cursor API says:"This interface provides random read-write access to the result set returned by a database query." For me it sounds, like: 1. the query is processed. 2. the result set is generated. 3. A cursor is created and linked to the result set. 4. The cursor iterates over a *limited* amount of result items. Am i wrong? I didn't use the Cursor yet.

Comment: It throws Exception: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "LIMIT": syntax error:

Comment: dn forget to add a space before `Limit` and yes, cursor providers random access since it can move to any record given the position(through `moveToPosition` method).but in our case we need only one record  :-/

Comment: Tried in different ways..With and without space before Limit but get one Exception...(

Comment: It's just the matter of performance i was curious about. So using Cursor does not relieve from writing smart queries. Got it. Thank you

Comment: Some wrote that content provider does not have argument "LIMIT".. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962528/limit-number-of-rows-in-cursor-query )

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
public Strin getContactByName(String name)
{
    String conact;
    //Query
    String query = "select * from CONTACTS where NAME = ?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {name});
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // Name Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        contact = "Not Found";
        return contact;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    contact = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME"));

    cursor.close();
    return contact;
}
```

It will return only the first contact matching that name.

Comment: it is not fit...i can get records(cursor) by contact's id. Need to get all emails without google's copies.. In my HTC database of contacts email has row "ACCOUNT_TYPE" but its row is not supported on all android phones. Want to check if DB has this row, but first need to get only one record for more efficiency.